# Changing background color based on first character on line

Tags: faces, font-lock

How can I change the font background based on the first character on a given line? Take for example:

```
(set-face-attribute 'marker-2 nil :background some_function)
```

where `some_function` returns `"blue"` if the first character of a line is equal to `%`, otherwise it returns `"red"`?

Comment: Typically, you would define two faces and write a font-lock rule that picks one or the other.

Comment: Take a look at [rainbow-mode](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/rainbow-mode.html). I am guessing you can propertize a line based on the first character, the same way `rainbow-mode` propertize color code strings (and some others IIRC)?